# Showing a nonzero multiplicative arithmetic function satisfies $f(1) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

let $f$ be multiplicative arithmetic function. if there exist a positive integer $n$ such that $f(n)$ is not equal to $0$ (so $f$ is not identically zero) prove that $f(1)=1$. 
I got that $gcd(1,n)=1$ and since $f$ is multiplicative then $f(n.1)=f(n)f(1)$. I do not know how to proceed further. Any help is appreciated Thank you.

Comment: So you have $f(n)=f(n)\times f(1)$....just chose $n$ such that you can divide by $f(n)$.

Comment: @lulu what do you mean ?like how do I divide by f(n)?

Comment: @lulu The way the question is phrased, a good $n$ is already chosen for you.

Comment: @Arthur what do you suggest? I am really lost

Comment: As @Arthur points out, you have already chosen $n$ such that $f(n)\neq 0$.  But then we can take your equation, $f(n)=f(n)\times f(1)$ and divide both sides by $f(n)$.

Comment: oh i see Thank you so much :)